# How can I interpret an HTTPS with non-utf8 characters?

Tags: networking, rust, https, utf-8

I'm working on a very simple and straightforward reverse proxy in rust without any external libraries. I'm come to my first roadblock. I've noticed that when I try to parse an *https* request into `utf8` it fails. I printed the request as a lossy string. Here is the output:

```
�f�^���;�r�;�d��N7# ^�8Đ�6 �m�xpPk�
����B]���Fi��֚*G]"�+�/̨̩�,�0�
�       ����/5�rus
```

I was thinking this has something to do with `ssl` because on the client side, it says something along the lines of "Secure Connection has Failed". I've looked into decoding `ssl` requests or whatever this is and have found nothing useful. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried parsing the request using several different solution from other platforms. They consisted of relying on `base64` and other `ssl` related crates meant for decoding text.

For more context, below is a general example for how I go about getting the output from above:

```rust
use std::{
    io::{Read, Result},
    net::TcpListener,
};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let server = TcpListener::bind("localhost:443")?;

    for mut stream in server.incoming().filter_map(Result::ok) {
        let mut buf = [0; 256];
        let bytes = stream.read(&mut buf)?;

        let utf8_lossy = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf); //  this contains the non-utf8 wumbo jumbo
        let utf8 = String::from_utf8(buf.to_vec()).unwrap(); //  this fails
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about *what* are you trying to achieve? TLS is a binary protocol, so you *shouldn't* interpret it as a UTF-8 encoded string.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I am trying to correctly interpret the contents of any HTTP/HTTPS request so that I can take that information and distribute it accordingly.

Comment: You should use an HTTP server library with TLS support to implement an HTTP server. You don't want to write your own HTTP and TLS libraries. You could try [axum_server](https://docs.rs/axum-server/latest/axum_server/) to get started.

Comment: @EvanSchwartzentruber HTTP or HTTPS? Because those are two very different protocols. What traffic is incoming on `localhost:80`?

Comment: https in encrypted. Interpreting encrypted data as text will always produce garbled nonsense. Parse and decode the request before you try to display it

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Sorry the `80` was supposed to be `443` a simple typo.

Comment: @SvenMarnachI totally would use another library. I know this is somewhat tedious and impractical work, but I find it interesting to do it on my own. I believe it'll give me a better and more in-depth understanding.

Comment: @Carson How do you think I should go about decoding the output? I've tried decoding it using `base64` and `openssl-sys`. I'm not sure what else I could use to attempt to decode.

Comment: @EvanSchwartzentruber, it's _not a string_.  Your code is trying to parse a string from the data.  That's _not what it is!_  If it's SSL, then it's binary.  There may be string components in it (though likely _not_ UTF-8), but you need to deal with it as the binary elements it is first, _and then_ deal with the string parts.  Trying to interpret it all as a string will not succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an https client connects with the server, they establish a secure socket to protect data transfer between them. The data that is being passed over this socket is not necessarily text, and cannot be interpreted as such.

The process of establishing a socket is a multi-step protocol, where the client sends a `ClientHello` message, to which you should reply with a `ServerHello` which contains your certificate. The client then replies with it's keys and some cipher information, before the socket is finally ready to be used for data. All of these initalization steps are happening with a binary protocol, that cannot be interpreted as text. That is the reason you're not seeing any sensible output.

Once that socket is setup, only then does http data begin to flow over the connection. This is likely what you're expecting to see, as it contains the familiar 'HTTP/1.1 GET', etc.

Openssl, the library you mentioned using, has a way to setup a socket that will perform handshakes for you. See the [docs](https://docs.rs/openssl/latest/openssl/ssl/index.html).